# Help using *args in tuple matching Python function

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, match, args

I am trying to build a function in python that yields values of two dictionaries IF a particular value from `dict1` matches a particular value of `dict2`. My function looks like this:

```
def dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, item1_pos, item2_pos):
"""Uses a tuple value from dict1 to search for a matching tuple value in dict2. If a match is found, the other values from dict1 and dict2 are returned."""
for item1 in dict1:
    for item2 in dict2:
        if dict1[item1][item1_pos] == dict2[item2][item2_pos]:
            yield(dict1[item1][2], dict2[item2][6])
```

I am using `dict_matcher` like this:

```
matches = [myresults for myresults in dict_matcher(dict1, dict2 , 2, 6)]
print(matches)
```

When I print `matches` I get a list of correctly matching dict1 and dict2 values like this:

`[('frog', 'frog'), ('spider', 'spider'), ('cricket', 'cricket'), ('hampster', 'hampster')]`

How can I add variable arguments to this function so that, in addition to printing the matching values from each dictionary, I can also print the other values of each dictionary item in instances where `dict1[item1][2] and dict2[item2][6]` match? Can I use *args? Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
Ok, there seems to be some confusion as to what I am trying to do so let me try another example.

`dict1 = {1: ('frog', 'green'), 2: ('spider', 'blue'), 3: ('cricket', 'red')}`

`dict2 = {a: ('frog', 12.34), b: ('ape', 22.33), c: ('lemur', 90.21)}`

`dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, 0, 0)` would find matching values for value[0] from dict1 and value[0] from dict2. In this case, the only match is 'frog'. My function above does this. What I am trying to do is extend the function to be able to print out other values from the dictionary items where `dict1[value][0] == dict2[value][0]` I want this to be specified in the function argument.

Comment: maybe i'm just being stupid, but your question seems confused.  the values 2 and 6 are used for item1_pos and item2_pos (args is empty) in the call, yet they appear as if they are args (in some weird way that makes no sense to me) later.

Comment: @andrewcooke sorry, i see that it is confusing. i updated my question so i hope it is clearer now.

Comment: hmmm.  should it also be `yield(dict1[item1][item1_pos], dict2[item2][item2_pos])` in the initial code block?

Comment: and even with that i have no idea what you mean by "the other values of each dictionary item".  do you mean that you'd like to see entries 1, 5 and 23 from dict1[item1] and 3, 15 and 22 from dict2[item2], for example?

Comment: I agree with andrew. I dont understand the usage you are looking for. What do you expect to use *args for? Can you give an example? *args would act like a list of arguments within your function. I'm not exactly sure what you intend to also pass, along with these item positions? Can you maybe also include an example of dict1 and dict2 data structures, and how you would like to see ideal results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you're calling it as

```
matches = [myresults for myresults in dict_matcher(dict1, dict2 , 2, 6)]
```

You should be calling it as

```
matches = list(dict_matcher(dict1, dict2 , 2, 6))
```

and it's signature is

```
def dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, item1_pos, item2_pos, *args):
```

So 4 arguments passed, and 4 named arguments. So `*args` results in `args = None`.

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but if you do

```
yield dict1[item1][item1_pos], dict2[item2][item2_pos]
```

You'll get the same thing as you get from doing

```
yield dict1[item1][2], dict2[item2][6]
```

If you want to get the whole matching items, do

```
yield dict1[item1], dict2[item2]
```

If you want to get one item from each, but not the matching item, do

```
def dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, item1_pos, item2_pos, other1_pos, other2_pos):
```

and

```
yield dict1[item1][other1_pos], dict2[item2][other2_pos]
```

and

```
matches = list(dict_matcher(dict1, dict2 , 2, 6, 3, 8))
```

or whatever instead of 3 and 8.

If you want to get several, but not all items, do

```
def dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, item1_pos, item2_pos, other1_poss, other2_poss):
```

and

```
yield [dict1[item1][i] for i in other1_poss], [dict2[item2][i] for i in other2_poss]
```

and

```
matches = list(dict_matcher(dict1, dict2 , 2, 6, (2, 3), (6, 8)))
```

or whatever instead of [2, 3] and [3, 8].

If this isn't what you meant, let me know.

Comment: yes, thank you for understanding my confusing problem!  `def dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, item1_pos, item2_pos, other1_pos, other2_pos)` is precisely what I want, however I am trying to use `*args` so that each time I call the function I can specify a different set of other1_pos and other2_pos values. sometimes i need values like this: other1_pos1, other1_pos2, other2_pos3. other times i need values like this: other1_pos3, other1_pos1, other2_pos6. can *args be used for what i am trying to do?

Comment: See the very last one in my answer. You don't need *args. Make two lists -- one of the items you want from dict 1, another of the ones you want from dict 2. Then pass those lists. That's what I do in the very last example. It will work fine for any number of items you want from each one. See the `(2, 3)` and `(6, 8)` on the last line of code? Those are the lists of ones you want.

Comment: I didn't initially realize your very last example was precisely what I wanted. Seriously, a huge thank you for sticking with me as long as you did. Your answer is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [slice objects](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice):

```
def dict_matcher(dict1, dict2, pos1, pos2, slicer1=(), slicer2=()):
    slice1 = slice(*slicer1) if slicer1 else slice(len(dict1))
    slice2 = slice(*slicer2) if slicer2 else slice(len(dict2))
    for data1 in dict1.values():
        for data2 in dict2.values():
            if data1[pos1] == data2[pos2]:
                yield data1[slice1], data2[slice2]

for result1, result2 in dict_matcher(my_dict, your_dict, 2, 6, (3, 8, 2), (2, 6)):
    print result1, result2
```

- `some_list[slice(3, 8, 2)]` is equivalent to `some_list[3:8:2]`,
  giving you every second element of `some_list`starting with the
  fourth element (which has index 3) up to the eighth element.
- `some_list[slice(2, 6)]` is equivalent to `some_list[2:6]`, giving
  you every element of `some_list`starting with the third element
  (which has index 2) up to the sixth element.
- `some_list[slice(7)]` is equivalent to `some_list[:7]`, giving you
  every element of `some_list`up to the seventh element.

If you omit the `slicer1/2` arguments, the function assumes you want the whole list and the slices are set accordingly.

Also, I removed unnecessary dictionary lookups.

Comment: I've never even used a slice object before. Thats interesting. I'm actually amazed you understood his question. I think I understand it now too after reading your answer, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to specify an arbitrary number of pairs of indexes to try to compare for matches?

Something like this?

```
def matcher(d1, d2, *args):
    indexes = zip(args[0::2], args[1::2])
    for a, b in indexes:
        for value1 in dict1.values():
            for value2 in dict2.values():
                x, y = value1[a], value2[b]
                    if x == y:
                        yield x, y

dict1 = {1: ('frog', 'green'), 2: ('spider', 'blue'), 3: ('cricket', 'red')}
dict2 = {a: ('frog', 12.34), b: ('ape', 22.33), c: ('lemur', 90.21)}

matches = list(matcher(d1, d2, 
                        0, 0, # first pair to search for matches
                        1, 1  # second pair, 
                        # ... and so on,
))

print matches
# [('frog', 'frog')]
```

I don't think this is terribly usable but this would do it.  This will still sort of work if you specify odd numbers of args due to the magic of slicing.  However, because of this the interface to your matcher function is going to be easy to use incorrectly.

I'd strongly consider something more like:

```
def matcher(d1, d2, indexes_to_check):
    ...
print list(matcher(d1, d2, [(0, 0), (1, 1), ...]))

def matcher(d1, d2, *indexes_to_check):
    ...
print list(matcher(d1, d2, (0, 0), (1, 1)))
```